# Values attribution in jeet column

Tags: stylus, jeet-grid

In Jeet documentation I see `column (ratios = 1, offset = 0, cycle = 0, uncycle = 0, gutter = jeet-gutter)` with the equal sign.

Then in the following paragraphs, the expression is using colons: `column(1/4, cycle: 4)`

I don't understand why the documentation is using two different attribution methods. In coding, afaik, there is a big difference between `:` and `=`, and I don't understand why the developer is using both.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`=` is used for default arguments in a mixin declaration. `:` is used for named arguments (when you need to pass an argument and don't want to worry about its position). See the Stylus documentation (http://stylus-lang.com/docs/functions.html)